# Why don't C++ structured bindings work with initializer lists?

Tags: c++

Why does this code not compile with an error message?

```cpp
#include <initializer_list>
    
int main() {
    auto [a, b] = { 1, 2 };
}
```

> error: cannot decompose inaccessible member 'std::initializer_list<int>::_M_array' of 'std::initializer_list<int>'

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/xbb7Gdnvz)

But, this code compiles and works just fine?

```cpp
#include <utility>
    
int main() {
    auto [a, b] = std::make_pair(1, 2);
}
```

What is so specific with an initializer list that makes its members inaccessible?

Is it any kind of assumption that an initializer list creates an object (of a class) with private fields (or even "inaccessible internal structure"), or is there something else at play?

Comment: Yes : https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0144r2.pdf *3.1 Should this syntax support initialization from an initializer_list<T>?
We think the answer has to be no, primarily because the size of an initializer_list is dynamic whereas the list of introduced names is static.*

Comment: its rather `std::pair` that is *special* to make it work with structured bindings

Comment: You cannot do neither `auto [a, b] = std::vector{1, 2};`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Structured binding work with arrays or tuple-like types. From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding):

> We use `E` to denote the type of the expression `e`. (In other words, `E` is the equivalent of `std::remove_reference_t<decltype((`e`))>`.)
>
> A structured binding declaration then performs the binding in one of three possible ways, depending on `E`:
>
> Case 1: if `E` is an array type, then the names are bound to the array elements.
>
> Case 2: if `E` is a non-union class type and `std::tuple_size<E>` is a complete type with a member named value (regardless of the type or accessibility of such member), then the "tuple-like" binding protocol is used.
>
> Case 3: if `E` is a non-union class type but `std::tuple_size<E>` is not a complete type, then the names are bound to the accessible data members of `E`.

[`std::initializer_list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) is neither an array, nor tuple-like, nor does it have any accessible members.

> What is so specific with initializer list that makes its members inaccessible?

It simply doesnt grant you direct access to the underlying array. Its a private member. `std::pair` on the other hand is tuple-like and its `first` and `second` can be accessed via `std::tuple_element`.

Comment: There is a `std::initializer_list` since the structure binding results in introducing a uniquely named variable `e` as if by `auto e = { 1, 2 }` ([dcl.struct.bind#1](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.struct.bind#1)), to which the binding actually binds, and the deduced type here is `std::initializer_list` ([dcl.type.auto.deduct#3](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type.auto.deduct#3)).

Comment: @YurkoFlisk thanks for enlightening me. I didnt know about this. And I can remove that paragraph